# Use different class upon available CPU support

Tags: c++

How do I change the used class upon available CPU features?

For example changing the used `Vector4`-class by supported SIMD on the client side:

```
bool has_sse = get_cpuid_info( "sse" );

if( has_sse ) {
    // use Vector4SIMD only in the entire app
} else {
    // fallback to a plain Vector4-class
}
```

I can think of some ways (edit: added suggestions):

- using dynamic libraries
- dynamic cast's
- virtual dispatch
- compiler specific attributes

How is this, or similar behaviour done in nowadays software?

Comment: Use virtual methods and have all the different implementations as subclasses of some master. Then when you instantiate the class, use the `if` statement to decide which subclass to create.

Comment: I prefer to have separate executables. Then have a launcher check the CPU and run the the desired executable.

Answer (score 0):

It could be compiler specific. Recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) offers specific [x86 builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/X86-Built-in-Functions.html) like `__builtin_cpu_supports` etc. See also the [`ifunc` function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bifunc_007d-attribute-2968)

Of course, as [Mark Ransom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5987/mark-ransom) commented, you could use virtual methods. But that might not worth the effort for very short and quick small functions (you want them to be inlined).

Comment: I was presuming the question was about choices made at run time, not compile time. Good point about short and quick functions, you'd want to reserve my technique for functions that try to accomplish a meaningful amount of work per call.